# Generate random numbers with specific text

Tags: python

```
randstring = 'test'.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=2))
```

I want to generate the text as `test1,test3`. The specific text is `'test'` and along with that I want to generate random numbers. I tried the above statement but result is like `'1test3'` and not `'test1,test3'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it down to two steps:

1. Generate `k` random numbers and concatenate them to the string.
2. `join` the strings with a comma.

You seem to have mixed up a bit with what to join, so it should look something like:

```
import random
import string

k = 2
randstring = ','.join("test" + random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(k))
```

Alternatively, using `choices` as you did:

```
randstring = ','.join("test" + num for num in random.choices(string.digits, k))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
n = random. randint(10, 99) 
randstring = 'test' + str(n)
```